# How to optimize enumerate in Python?

Tags: python, loops, enumerate

Running loops is extremely slow in Python, but having an `enumerate` loop I try to get rid of.

Here are the inputs:

```
T  =  3
N  =  5000
k  =  [0.1193354,0.27447143,0.42960745]
P  =  [0.31600902,0.02144897,0.03998757,0.00708576,0.27952587,0.02057329,0.01790612,0.00689641,0.29056699]
cont  =  np.arange(T*T)
G     =  np.zeros([T,T])
```

Here is the `enumerate` loop:

```
dis   =  rv_discrete(values=(cont, P))

for t, i_t in enumerate(dis.rvs(size = N)):
    Q  =  np.zeros([T,T])
    if i_t // T == i_t % T:
        Q[i_t // T, i_t % T] = c[i_t // T, i_t % T] / (1 - beta)
    else:
        Q[i_t // T, i_t % T] = c[i_t // T, i_t % T]
    
    G  += Q / P[i_t]
```

Basically, the code randomly draws 5000 samples and put each draw into a n by n zero matrix with a certain order. For example, if `i_t // T == i_t % T` the element goes to the diagonal line, otherwise it goes to the corresponding location. And `G` is the sum of each random draw devides its weight.

**Goal**: it is possible to reformulate the `enumerate` loop into a pure matrices computation? Or get rid of the loop and make it faster?

Comment: Your loop doesn't use `t` at all, so why do you need the `enumerate`?

Comment: Is one of the `i_t // T` parts in `Q[i_t // T, i_t // T]` supposed to be `i_t % T`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the question is a simplified version, and it does not necessarily need t. But anyway it’s still a loop:(

Comment: If they *are* equal? But there's no point if they're equal.

Comment: Sorry @user2357112 I have re-edited my question.

Comment: Have you noticed that you're always computing `i_t // T` and `i_t % T` three times each (in the posted code alone)?  Why not compute them once each, and save the results so they can be used later?  Hint: If you want your code to run fast, don't make it do unnecessary work.

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes, code has been changed according to your advice.